# Android deep linking works in ADB, but not browser

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am trying to add deep linking to my app. I have added 2 intent filters to one of my activities, one filter for the "http" scheme, and another for my custom scheme (I'm using "example"). I have added one intent filter per scheme, based on the info in this SO ([Deep-linking intent does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808777/deep-linking-intent-does-not-work)), so that I can handle both `example://test` and `http://www.example.com/test` type of links.

Here is my XML:

```
        <activity
    android:name="com.myapp.myapp.SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="Intent Filter label">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/test2” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/test2" />

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="Intent Filter label">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://test2” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="test2" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

They are loading correctly when I test in ADB:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.MAIN -d "example://test2" com.myapp.myapp
```

returns

> ```
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN dat=example://test2 pkg=com.myapp.myapp }
> Status: ok
> Activity: com.myapp.myapp/com.app.myapp.SplashActivity
> ThisTime: 357
> TotalTime: 357
> Complete
> ```

However, I get absolutely nothing in a browser. When I try this in a browser:
"`example://test2`" in FF I get "`couldn't find an app to open this link`" and in Chrome and the Native Browser, it opens up new Google search for "`example://test2`".

When I try the other style: "`http://www.example.com/test2`" it just tries to navigate to that web page in all 3 browsers.

I am deploying the app to my phone from Android Studio. I have also tried by generating a debug APK, sending it to my phone, and installing. Same result for both.
**What am I doing wrong?** I've followed the guide (https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) to the letter as far as I can tell. **Does my app need to be in the store for the deep linking to work?**

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I am having a similar issue and tho this answer was not my problem it did answer my questions about how to setup deep linking in android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ughh, my action was MAIN when it should have been VIEW...

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

...

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

Comment: new to android can you provide detail on which line of XML you made changes, and it works facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation seems to be correct and also, if you're testing your app in your device, it does not need to be available on Playstore.

Have you tried testing through a QR code? As is demonstrated in Google documents - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The scheme (and probably host) have to be in **all lower case**.

From the [uni_link](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package i copied the deep link intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
      <data
        <!-- THIS HAS TO BE IN ALL LOWER CASE -->
        android:scheme="[YOUR_SCHEME]"
        <!-- android:scheme="[your_scheme]" -->
        android:host="[YOUR_HOST]" />
</intent-filter>
```

and pasted in my package name `com.myPackage.app` as the scheme. For the host I put `localhost`.
Changing the scheme to all lower case `com.mypackage.app` allowed the deep link to work.

You can use [this site](https://halgatewood.com/deeplink/) to test the deep link without using adb.

PS: This is not true for iOS where the `CFBundleURLName` and `CFBundleURLSchemes` can contain uppercase letters.