# Deep Linking not working

Tags: android

```
activity
        android:name=".activity.rechargetab.RechargeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="mobileleb"
                android:host="recharge/checkout/status" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I try mobileleb://recharge/checkout/status from the browser it searches google.Its not working. It does not start RechargeActivity.

Comment: Check the accepted answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808777/deep-linking-intent-does-not-work). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

add android:autoVerify="true" to intent-filter and specify scheme="http" or "https" or both

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.rechargetab.RechargeActivity">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mobileleb" />
                <data android:pathPattern ="/recharge/checkout/status" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```